# How do I access/update the blue number next to my Facebook application through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If, for example, someone makes a move in Scrabble against me, when I next log into Facebook there will be a little blue number "1" in my left sidebar next to the "SCRABBLE" application.  Problem is, I have no idea what this number is called, so I don't know how to even look for it in the graph API!  Anyone know what this is called/have the graph API link for the documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [Applications Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). And how to access these requests is simple:

```
GET /me/apprequests/
```

Or using the PHP-SDK:

```
$facebook->api("/me/apprequests/");
```

I've written an in-depth tutorials on how to [send](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/) and [handle](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/) Facebook Applicaiton requests that may help you understand the concept.